# PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 19): At the Theater

Tags: crosswords, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2022](//puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7414/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](/q/119060) [<kbd>Next Door></kbd>](/q/119081)</sub>

---

[image]

#### Across

**1** Pollo accompanier
**6** Flies
**11** Ministerial dress
**14** Excrement
**15** Gotta go *(2 words)*
**16** Primary
**18** Try to win
**19** An Asian fruit
**20** A record
**22** A putative play about what one really wants beneath the Christmas tree *(4 words)*
**25** City near Ramla
**26** Shawarmas, sort of
**27** Blacklight emission: *abbr.*
**28** King from Benjamin
**31** Line from *Pulp Fiction (3 words)*
**33** Polish film of 2018
**34** Comparative, in tempo
**35** HIV, e.g.
**36** *(with 55 Across)* A Teletubby
**38** A putative play about a *Frozen* princess at Yuletide *(2 words)*
**45** Curry
**46** Goodbye
**47** Theft
**50** A real play, putatively about Santa's visit *(3 words)*
**53** It slips my mind: *abbr.*
**54** It decides what's Span.
**55** *(see 36 Across)*
**56** Saxophonist-bandleader Georgie
**59** Relevant
**64** Bono mate
**65** Flyer Chang
**66** Boomerish, perhaps
**67** 2022 hurricane
**69** A putative play about Santa's trip *(3 words)*
**75** Soap writer Anderson
**76** Try fooling *(2 words)*
**77** Fork and knife, for example
**78** It may be ethnic
**79** Hammond startup
**80** Overweight
**81** However
**82** Seaweed jellies
**83** Mayan ethnohistorian Eduard

#### Down

**1** Like fine wine
**2** Germanic letter
**3** Darn
**4** *(see 9 Down)*
**5** Tornado rider
**6** New Zealand evergreen
**7** Putative Miss Huggenkiss of Springfield
**8** "El ___ Pasa"
**9** *(with 4 Down)* The playwright *(2 words)*
**10** Floor in London
**11** Nannies
**12** Where to bowl
**13** A quantity of garbage, perhaps
**17** Innocent
**21** Omicronian leader
**23** Mrs. Bunker
**24** Mikado lyrics *(2 words)*
**28** Baths
**29** Fails to be
**30** Early ISP
**32** Quantum electrodynamicist Paul
**33** Deejay Casey
**35** Appt. book, perhaps
**37** A horse loser
**39** Pest on plants
**40** RStudio, e.g.
**41** Game series begun in 1989
**42** It may be high
**43** Saki
**44** Surrender
**48** Without a date
**49** Those in Scotland
**51** Mesopotamian
**52** Electronics manufacturer
**56** Knee tissues: *abbr.*
**57** Oopsies: *hyph.*
**58** Isolated
**60** Italy's heel
**61** Cheering
**62** Nicaraguan leader
**63** Vex
**64** Dress
**66** Grey snow
**68** Cars
**70** You are likely to be eaten by it
**71** Hamm and Lord
**72** Coward
**73** Otherwise
**74** Flemish river

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Finished grid:

> [image]

#### Solutions:

##### Across

> **1** Pollo accompanier: Pollo con **Arroz**
>  **6** Flies: Time flies/ time **races**
>  **11** Ministerial dress: [**Alb**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alb)
>  **14** Excrement: **Guano**
>  **15** Gotta go *(2 words)*: **I'm out**
>  **16** Primary: **Main**
>  **18** Try to win: **Enter** a competition
>  **19** An Asian fruit: **Mango**
>  **20** A record: **Annal**
>  **22** A putative play about what one really wants beneath the Christmas tree *(4 words)*: **Desire Under the Fir** from [Desire Under the Elms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desire_Under_the_Elms)
>  **25** City near Ramla  : [**Lod**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lod)
>  **26** Shawarmas, sort of: **Doners** (sort of Döners)
>  **27** Blacklight emission: *abbr.*: **U**ltra-**v**iolet **radiation**
>  **28** King from Benjamin: **Saul** (from the bible)
>  **31** Line from *Pulp Fiction (3 words)*: **I dare ya!** I double dare ya, ...
>  **33** Polish film of 2018: [**Kler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clergy_(film))
>  **34** Comparative, in tempo: **Più** more, as in "più lento"-more slowly
>  **35** HIV, e.g.: **S**exually **T**ransmitted **I**nfection
>  **36** *(with 55 Across)* A Teletubby: **Laa**-Laa
>  **38** A putative play about a *Frozen* princess at Yuletide *(2 words)*: **Anna Christmassy** from [Anna Christie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Christie)
>  **45** Curry: [**Steph**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Curry)
>  **46** Goodbye: **Adieu**
>  **47** Theft: **Heist**
>  **50** A real play, putatively about Santa's visit *(3 words)*: [**The Iceman Cometh**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iceman_Cometh)
>  **53** It slips my mind: *abbr.* **I** **d**on't **r**ecall
>  **54** It decides what's Span.: [**R**eal **A**cademia **E**spañola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Spanish_Academy)
>  **55** *(see 36 Across)*: Laa-**Laa**
>  **56** Saxophonist-bandleader Georgie: [**Auld**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgie_Auld)
>  **59** Relevant: **Apropos**
>  **64** Bono mate: [The **Edge**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Edge) (from U2)
>  **65** Flyer Chang: **Cho** from Harry Potter (?)
>  **66** Boomerish, perhaps: **Square**, as in boringly conventional
>  **67** 2022 hurricane: [**Ian**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Ian)
>  **69** A putative play about Santa's trip *(3 words)*: **Long Night's Journey** from [Long Day's Journey Into Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Day%27s_Journey_into_Night)
>  **75** Soap writer Anderson: [**Sheri**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheri_Anderson)
>  **76** Try fooling *(2 words)*: **Lie to**
>  **77** Fork and knife, for example: **Tools**
>  **78** It may be ethnic: **Slur**
>  **79** Hammond startup: **InGen** from Jurassic Park
>  **80** Overweight: **Obese**
>  **81** However: **Yet**
>  **82** Seaweed jellies: [**Agars**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agar)
>  **83** Mayan ethnohistorian Eduard: [**Seler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Seler)

##### Down

> **1** Like fine wine: **Aged**
>  **2** Germanic letter: **Rune**
>  **3** Darn: **Rats!**
>  **4** *(see 9 Down)*: Eugene **O'Neill** wrote the plays of the theme
>  **5** Tornado rider: **Zorro** ([Tornado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_(horse)))
>  **6** New Zealand evergreen: [**Rimu**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dacrydium_cupressinum)
>  **7** Putative Miss Huggenkiss of Springfield: **Amanda** (A man to hug and kiss), references The Simpsons
>  **8** "El ___ Pasa": [**Condor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_C%C3%B3ndor_Pasa_(song))
>  **9** *(with 4 Down)* The playwright *(2 words)*: **Eugene** O'Neill wrote the plays of the theme.
>  **10** Floor in London: **Storey**
>  **11** Nannies: [**Amahs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amah_(occupation))
>  **12** Where to bowl: A bowling **lane**
>  **13** A quantity of garbage, perhaps: **Binful**
>  **17** Innocent: **naive**
>  **21** Omicronian leader: **Lrrr** (from Futurama)
>  **23** Mrs. Bunker: [**Edith**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edith_Bunker)
>  **24** Mikado lyrics *(2 words)*: [The Flowers That Bloom in the Spring, **Tra la**](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Mikado/The_flowers_that_bloom_in_the_spring)
>  **28** Baths: **Spas**
>  **29** Fails to be: **Ain't**
>  **30** Early ISP: [**UUNet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUNET)
>  **32** Quantum electrodynamicist Paul: [**Dirac**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Dirac)
>  **33** Deejay Casey: [**Kasem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casey_Kasem)
>  **35** Appt. book, perhaps: **Sched.** (ule)
>  **37** A horse loser: **Ashoe** ["For want of a shoe, a horse was lost."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Want_of_a_Nail)
>  **39** Pest on plants: [**Aphid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphid)
>  **40** RStudio, e.g.: **I**ntegrated **D**evelopment **E**nvironment
>  **41** Game series begun in 1989: [**Sim**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimCity)
>  **42** It may be high: **Tea**
>  **43** Saki: [**Munro**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saki)
>  **44** Surrender: **Yield**
>  **48** Without a date: **Stag**
>  **49** Those in Scotland: **Thae**
>  **51** Mesopotamian: **Iraqi**
>  **52** Electronics manufacturer: **Casio**
>  **56** Knee tissues: *abbr.*: **[ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anterior_cruciate_ligament)s**
>  **57** Oopsies: *hyph.*: **Uh-Ohs**
>  **58** Isolated: **Lonely**
>  **60** Italy's heel: [**Puglia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apulia)
>  **61** Cheering: **Rahing**
>  **62** Nicaraguan leader: [Daniel **Ortega**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Ortega)
>  **63** Vex: **Pester**
>  **64** Dress: **Enrobe**
>  **66** Grey snow: [**Snirt**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snirt)
>  **68** Cars: **Autos**
>  **70** You are likely to be eaten by it: [**Grue**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grue_(monster))
>  **71** Hamm and Lord: **Jons** ([Jon Hamm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Hamm), [Jon Lord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Lord))
>  **72** Coward: [**Noel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No%C3%ABl_Coward)
>  **73** Otherwise: **Yet**
>  **74** Flemish river: [**Yser**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yser)